# How change the value of this.something with a looping

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    if (this.name === '') {
        this.name= 'None';
    }
    if (this.obs === '') {
        this.obs = 'None';
    }
```

Guys, how can i dry this code? I am trying like this:

```
var v = [this.name, this.obs];

for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
   if(v[i] === '') {
       v[i] = 'None';
   } 
};
```

But is not working at all...

Comment: @meskobalazs he makes an array of object properties

Comment: @kidwon my bad, you are right

Comment: please, add `console.log(v)` after `v` creation, to check if it does not contain `undefined`-s or something else that you don't expect

Comment: [ '', '' ] @GlenSwift

Comment: Just to rephrase the question, you want to replace all `null` elements in an array with the string `'None'`?

Comment: nop, i want replace all the elements with the value of '' in THIS for 'None'.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, this question is off topic for CR.  Do not post this question on CR.  We only Review working Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a function.
something like this

```
function setToNoneIfEmpty (stringInput) {
    if (stringInput === '') {
        stringInput = 'none';
    }
    return stringInput;
}
```

to make this cleaner you should make use of a ternary statement and just return the value and not reassign the parameter, so the function looks like this

```
function setToNoneIfEmpty (stringInput) {
    return stringinput === '' ? 'None' : stringinput;
}
```

with this you should be able to pass in `this.name` and `this.obs` and the function will change them accordingly.  you would call them like this

```
this.name = setToNoneIfEmpty(this.name);
this.obs = setToNoneIfEmpty(this.obs);
```

Your original code that isn't working, isn't working because you created a multi-dimensional array and then didn't access the values as a multi-dimensional array.

The way that I propose will work a lot better and is easier to read

---

I am not a Pro at Javascript (By a longshot) but someone mentioned to me that it could be done differently, where you would actually access the object and pass in the object property that you want to check.

```
function setToNoneIfEmpty(obj, name) {
    if (obj[name] === '') { 
        obj[name] = 'None'; 
    } 
}
```

so instead of passing in a variable to return a string, we pass in an object and the property name,  this makes the code even DRY-er as you can see when we put it to use

```
setToNoneIfEmpty(this, 'name')
setToNoneIfEmpty(this, 'obs')
```

Comment: @Malachi Still won't work. The idea of the `outparam.value` trick is that we pass in a reference type, which we can mutate inside the function. But we can't really do that here – we'd have to write `var param = {'value': this.name}; SetToNoneIfEmpty(param); this.name = param.value` to get around copying of values, which defeats the purpose of DRYing the code.

Comment: In JavaScript, `''` evaluates to `false`

Comment: @amon This *might* work because he is assigning the value back to the original property.

Comment: Yes, the current [edit of the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28434859/2) strikes a sane balance between DRY and simplicity.

Comment: However, the body of the function could be simplified to: `return stringInput || 'None';`

Comment: @DavinTryon Probably yes, but that wouldn't be exactly equivalent to the code in the question. Consider what happens when the property is `false` or `null` or `undefined`. OP's code will leave them be, using the `||` operator would replace them.

Comment: @amon `setToNoneIfFalsey()`?  :)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that we can access the properties of an object not only like `object.property` but also via the subscript operator: `object['property']`. Therefore, we can loop over all names of the properties we want to change:

```
var propertyNames = ['name', 'obs'];

for(var i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
    if(this[propertyNames[i]] === '') {
       this[propertyNames[i]] = 'None';
   } 
};
```

With `Array.forEach`, the code becomes a bit simpler:

```
['name', 'obs'].forEach(function (key) {
    if (this[key] === '') {
        this[key] = 'None';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for..in` loop along with OR operator.

```
for(var key in this)
   this[key] = this[key] || 'None';
```

`for..in` loop loops through the enumerable properties of `this` and `this[key]` gets assigned to itself, if it isn't `''`. If it is `''`, then `'None'` will be assigned to it, as `''` is considered *falsey*

Comment: `for in` is unsafe for arrays, and it should not be used.

Comment: Glen Swift and mesokobalazs, `this` is an Object as OP shows in his first snippet.

Comment: Downvoters, I'm using for..in loop only on an Object, as `this` is object, whose properties, OP is making an Array of. I ain't using Array.

Comment: You loop through `this` but OP wants to loop through `v`

Comment: @GlenSwift there's no mention of it. OP said, *he just tried*. What he is trying to is what I've done.

Comment: @DRX that two lines of code is all you need. I AM NOT USING AN ARRAY . So, you don't need to worry about how many properties.

Comment: @GlenSwift The OP has created an array of properties from `this` to iterate through. This bypasses the need to.

Comment: like i said before.. i i can't make a loop in  'this', because 'this' have to many properties.. and i want target only the name and the obs.

Comment: If it's just the two properties, then it's not exactly DRY. There's no point trying to add all this logic for two properties.

Comment: "nop, i want replace all the elements with the value of '' in THIS for 'None'.", well which is it?!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var v = [this.name, this.obs];

v.forEach(function(elem){
    if(!elem) elem = 'NONE';
})
```